# Proving prime counting inequality

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$ 2n \ln 2 \leq \sum_{\{p \,\mid \, p \leq 2n+1, \,p\text{ is prime}\}} \ln(2n+1) = \pi(2n+1) \cdot \ln(2n+1)$$

Hint: Use $$\operatorname{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, 2n+1) \leq \prod_{\{p \,\mid \, p \leq 2n+1, \,p\text{ is prime}\}} p^{\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{\ln p}}$$
and
$$ 4^n \leq \operatorname{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, 2n+1) $$

I have already proven the hints, but I'm not sure how I use these in order to prove the first statement.

Comment: Take logs on both sides of both of the hints.

Comment: I can see how the log would be useful, but which base would that be?

Comment: There is only one base for logarithms, and it's the one that already appears in several of the formulas in your question.

Comment: Oh thank you. Apparently I forgot a couple of logarithm identities!

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities, for $x \geq 17$ you have $\pi(x)>x/\ln x$, then for $n\geq 8$ 
$$\ln(2n+1)\pi(2n+1)>\ln(2n+1) \frac{2n+1}{\ln(2n+1)} >2n\ln 2\;.$$
For $1\leq n \leq 7$ you could check case by case